# use 2 different versions of same control (dll) at the same time on same machine?

Tags: .net, dll, activex, versions

I'm using a3rd party component in my project and I recently upgraded to their latest version which fixed bug 'A'

unfortunately, while it solved bug 'A', another part has gotten completely unstable, so it introduced a bug 'B'.

Since 'A' and 'B' are in completely different contexts, I want to have both versions of the control installed and use the one in one case where bug 'B' is not relevant, and the other one in the case that bug 'A' is not relevant.

of course, everything until a proper fix has been issued by the 3rd party developer

Anyone any thought how this can be done?

R

p.s. the dll needs to be registered with regsvr32... I suspect this is the point where it makes itself findable... I'm hoping with some trickery it is here we can register the thing double under a different name

Comment: Is the 3rd party component a COM component, or a managed code component ?

Comment: a com component... not managed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can deploy different version of a COM component and use them without registration. This feature of registration-free COM has been introduced with Windows XP and requires you to deploy a .manifest file with the appropriate settings.

Have a look at [**Registration-Free Activation of COM Components**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx) and [**Escape DLL Hell:
Simplify App Deployment with ClickOnce and Registration-Free COM**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188708.aspx).

Comment: although it seems like a lot of hassle (config files etc).. this looks exactly what I'm looking for. I'm going to try this

Comment: Although I don't think it is possible to use two different versions of the same COM component within the same process/application as they are still identified by their GUID. In that case the solution proposed by Charles might be better.

Comment: at the end of article 1 they say (in the conclusion) It enables applications with dependencies on different versions of the same COM component to share an infrastructure and to load those various COM component versions side by side in an echo of the .NET Framework versioning and deployment mechanism.-------does this mean it can or can't be done?

Comment: @CharlesBretana Upvoting your comment for using the word promulgate. I actually had to look that one up.

Comment: Thanks for the links, the "Registration-Free" link definitely helped. The other 2 links are broken now. They just point to a list of MSDN magazines.

Answer (score 0):

You can only register one COM dll of the same type on your machine... this is why the GAC is introduced by .Net

Comment: That is true, but you can also use components without registering them.

Comment: Not a COM component you can't.

Comment: Yes, since Windows XP you can use COM without the Registry. See the link in my answer or here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188708.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If the third party component is a COM component, then you're on the right track, you need to register it twice using different names/Guids.

EDIT: see divo answer about multiple COM registration... After XP you can do this now...
But before that the only way to do this (short of having the source code and recompiling a new dll yourself with different registration guids), was to manually modify the type library, and replace the existing guids with new ones.  This would be extremely difficult.  (There may exist a tool to do this, but if there is I don;t know of it)  The type library, by the way may be embedded in the dll itself, or it may be in a separate *.tlb file (common for VB6 components)

If, otoh, the component is a managed code component, then the registry may only be necessary for integration into visual studio, and it will be sufficient to just copy the dll into the application folder for the executable you are using it in...